# How to deprecate/remove old Azure Devops tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have a release task (internal) that is currently in v4. I'd like start encouraging my users to move to the latest version. I followed [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/build-task-schema?view=vsts#bundle-multiple-versions-of-buildrelease-tasks-within-one-extension) instructions to bundle multiple versions of the task, then I was hoping I could use the deprecated tag, but no such luck. It looks like that only works when the [highest version of the task is marked deprecated](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/deprecatedtasks.md#deprecated-tasks) and it has other implications such making the entire task harder to find.

How are tasks such as the [Pester Test Runner](https://github.com/rfennell/vNextBuild/wiki/Pester-Task) only making later versions of the task (currently v6-v8 in this case) available? I tried publishing a version of my extension with the v1 visibility empty, and then with the entire task folder deleted, but v1 of the task was still available in the Azure DevOps ui in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can’t do that. For the task just has v6-v8, the author just published v6-v8 version, so there isn’t v1, v2 etc… version.

You can make current task extension as deprecated and publish a new task extension (different id).